# O que é deadlock no SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando resolver um problema com um erro no SQL Server e vendo [uma pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation), na resposta é citado um possível '*deadlock*' no SQL Server. O que é isto?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Um deadlock acontece quando duas ou mais tarefas bloqueiam uma à outra permanentemente, sendo que cada uma tem o bloqueio de um recurso, que a outra tarefa está tentando bloquear. Por exemplo:

- A transação A adquire um bloqueio compartilhado da linha 1.
- A transação B adquire um bloqueio compartilhado da linha 2.
- A transação A agora solicita um bloqueio exclusivo na linha 2 e é
  bloqueado até que a transação B termine e libere o bloqueio
  compartilhado que tem na linha 2.
- A transação B agora solicita um bloqueio exclusivo na linha 1 e é
  bloqueado até que a transação A termine e libere o bloqueio
  compartilhado que tem na linha 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A transação A não pode terminar até que a transação B termine, mas a transação B está bloqueada pela transação A. Essa condição é também chamada de dependência cíclica: a transação A tem uma dependência da transação B, e a transação B fecha o círculo tendo uma dependência da transação A.

[Neste post no fórum do Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/latam/archive/2010/03/18/deadlocks-no-sql-server-2008-o-que-fazer-para-resolv-los.aspx) fala mais sobre os processos de solução do deadlock.

Answer (score 31):

Isso ilustra bem o que é um *deadlock*:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Existem quatro condições para a ocorrência de *deadlock*:

- Condição de exclusão mútua:  Em um determinado instante, cada recurso está em uma de duas situações: ou associado a um único processo ou disponível.
- Condição de posso e espera:  Processos que, em um determinado instante, retêm recursos concedidos anteriormente podem requisitar novos recursos.
- Condição de não preempção:  Recursos concedidos previamente a um processo não podem ser tomados a força desse processo, eles devem ser explicitamente liberados pelo processo que os retém.
- Condição de espera circular:  Deve existir um encadeamento circular de dois ou mais processos; cada um deles encontra-se à espera de um recurso que está sendo usado pelo membro seguinte dessa cadeia.

Todas essas condições **devem ocorrer simultaneamente** para que ocorra um *deadlock*.

---

Em relação ao seu problema, verifique se alguma transação não está retendo algum recurso que outra transação precisa.

Referência: 
 [Introdução ao *DeadLock* - DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-deadlock/24794#ixzz3aUtKHWXw)

Comment: Essa aqui merece ser a resposta aceita só por causa da foto. +1.

Comment: Deixo aqui uma experiência: Recentemente tivemos um problema com isso aqui na empresa. Um usuário estava fazendo alguma alteração em uma pré-venda, enquanto outro tentou transformá-la em venda. Os devs optaram por criar um campo 'lock' e, quando/enquanto algum user estiver alterando algum dado na pré-venda, ela não poderá ser transformada em venda.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez - Lembro que, quando fui apresentar um trabalho sobre Sistemas Operacionais, usei essa imagem para explicar o que era deadlock. Acho que 100% da turma entendeu. kkkk

Comment: Eu era admin de uma página chamada Computação Depressão. Lembro de ter pego essa imagem e ter colocado em um desmotivado. O resultado foi [este](https://scontent-gru.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/1654130_486866364752309_1619390936_n.jpg?oh=ddf7fff26d17d31528e9fc92fbd7019f&oe=5606F928)

Comment: Ótima representação (foto)!

Answer (score 17):

**Deadlock** não é um conceito exclusivo de banco de dados, mas sim de aplicações concorrentes. [Em poucas palavras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock):

> É uma situação em que duas ou mais ações concorrentes estão cada uma esperando que a outra termine, e, portanto, isto nunca ocorre.

Para o caso de um banco de dados, um *deadlock* é provocado normalmente havendo transações, e envolvendo [travas exclusivas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). Travas exclusivas normalmente aparecem em operações de modificação.

Suponha duas transações, A e B. A precisa modificar as mesmas tabelas que B, mas B já pediu trava exclusiva em alguma das tabelas que A precisa modificar. O resultado é que A pode pedir trava exclusiva em outras tabelas que B também irá utilizar, resultando no *deadlock*.

[O próprio banco de dados possui alguns mecanismos internos para evitar *deadlock*](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178104%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), mas o mecanismo não é infalível e normalmente demanda ações do usuário.