# O que é controle de concorrência?

Tags: terminologia, concorrência

Sobre os estudos que eu estava fazendo  no momento em que eu perguntei [O que é um semáforo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211354), me informaram que, pra eu entender melhor sobre esse termo, eu deveria estudar sobre *Controle de Concorrência*.

Alguém poderia me explicar do que se trata?

Comment: Só achei referente a banco de dados, [Técnicas de controle de
concorrência (CC)](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~thelma/gradu/MC526/turma-2009/Slides-526/Aula17-Controle-Concorr.pdf)

Comment: Será o controle de concorrência trata problemas do tipo [deadlock](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64484/o-que-%C3%A9-deadlock-no-sql-server)?

Comment: A [página em inglês da wikipedia sobre o assunto é excelente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De uma maneira bem simples, o controle de concorrência visa gerenciar o acesso a recursos compartilhados. O objetivo é controlar como múltiplos acessos podem utilizar um recurso sem conflitos, porque o acesso concorrente sou simultâneo pode gerar inconsistência dos dados.
Isso não se restringe a bancos de dados, mas podem ser variáveis de memória, arquivos físicos, *threads*, etc.

Existem diferentes formas de de gerenciar a concorrência (semáforo é uma delas):

- **Monitor** é uma técnica utilizada para sincronizar tarefas que compartilham um recurso. ou seja, o monitor oferece uma interface para permitir a manipulação de um recurso compartilhado. Para tanto utiliza uma trava de exclusão mútua, que consiste de variáveis de controle e regras para liberar ou travar o recurso.
  De maneira prática, o monitor basicamente é uma classe que controla o recurso, assim quando for preciso requisitá-lo devemos enviar o pedido para ela.
- **Lock** é um mecanismo que isola o acesso a um recurso, limitando a um acesso de escrita por vez. Com isso, ele gerencia uma fila de acessos, ou seja, o primeiro a solicitar o *lock* ganha acesso ao recurso, e os acessos seguintes entram numa fila aguardando até que o *lock* seja liberado para ser concedido acesso ao próximo da fila. É bastante usado em bancos de dados para controlar o acesso a tabelas e registros.
- **Semáforo** é um mecanismo de concorrência que controla a quantidade de acessos simultâneos a um recurso compartilhado. Seria semelhante a um semáforo de trânsito, mas não por tempo, e sim por quantidade de veículos que podem acessar uma via. Quando o número máximo de recursos disponíveis é atingido, as solicitações devem aguardar alguma tarefa ser concluída para ter acesso ao recurso compartilhado.

Alguns links interessantes sobre concorrência e semáforos:
https://www.revista-programar.info/artigos/threads-semaforos-e-deadlocks-o-jantar-dos-filosofos/

https://brizeno.wordpress.com/tag/semaforos/

http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~frank.siqueira/INE5645/3.%20Controle%20de%20Concorrencia.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta anterior, com outras palavras e exemplificando, é o que acontece em seu computador: Há vários programas e threads "querendo" ser executados pelo processador, usar a dados da cache, da memoria RAM, acessar dispositivos I/O, entre outros. O sistema precisa gerenciar isso de forma que não gere confusão entre informações, endereços de memoria, ou ate mesmo quando um programa/thread entra em região critica. 
*Impedir ou liberar acesso dos dispositivos quando puderem ser usados.*