# Executar um script SQL em transação sem que ele bloquei outros scripts que acessem a mesma tabela

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transações

Alguem sabe me dizer se tem como eu executar um script SQL Server em transação sem que ele bloquei outros scripts que tentem acessar a mesma tabela?

Criei um programa em c# que que acessa minha base de dados em transação (readUncommited). Não posso realizar commit e nem rollback enquanto o programa estiver em execução.

Porém, preciso que outros programas (que estão rodando fora de transação) acessem as mesmas tabelas para fazerem update, insert, etc. No entanto eles travam e as vezes entram em deadlock

Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível criar uma transação em c# que não bloqueie o acesso a outros processos?

Answer (score 4):

O que você quer fazer é algo contra a natureza de uma transação. Se não quer um lock na linha, tabela, pagina, etc mais demorado, então não deve executar uma transação, apenas execute os comandos e deixa e *engine* do **SQL Server** gerenciar isso.

Apenas para pensar no que você está propondo fazer: imagine que um script que, dentro de uma transação altera o nome de um cliente, e, enquanto a transação ainda não foi finalizada ( `commit/rollback`) um outro script altere a mesma informação do mesmo registro, como o banco de dados vai decidir qual alteração persistir quando ambos fizerem `commit`? Isso também poderia gerar a situação de *deadlock* (leia mais aqui: [O que é deadlock no SQL Server?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64484/o-que-%C3%A9-deadlock-no-sql-server/64492))

Isso não faz sentido, é para evitar isso que existem locks. Você pode acessar um recurso com lock para leitura, um por exemplo um comando `select` (`readUncommited` como comentou na pergunta), mas não para alterações concorrentes, pois está bloqueado.

Se não houver transação, o primeiro script vai ganhar um lock e o segundo vai entrar na fila e aguardar o lock finalizar, então a informação mais atual será do segundo, mas houve lock de qualquer maneira, não é possível duas requisições alterando ao mesmo tempo.

Respondendo a sua pergunta, não dá pra se fazer isso. Não é bem transação em si quem bloqueia os recursos, são os comandos de alteração, e isso acontece com ou sem transação, a diferença é que numa transação é mais perceptível pois geralmente a transação demora um pouco mais, mas não dá pra evitar um lock quando um comando de alteração é executado, para que o banco garanta a integridade dos dados.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como fazer isso, infelizmente isso fere regras de consistência do SQL Server (e de qualquer um outro sgbd). Você pode tentar fazer uma redundancia de banco, no caso, um secundário que será atualizado sempre que o outro tiver um insert, update ou delete (parecido com um trigger). No caso, poderá acessar normalmente o banco secundário.