# O que é o travamento otimista e pessimista?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, ciência-da-computação, concorrência

Como se diferenciam *optimistic* e *pessimistic locking* no contexto de banco de dados?

Todos os produtos possuem isto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O travamento pessimista é muito mais simples de entender porque você efetivamente coloca uma trava (*lock*), ou seja, você diz que vai mexer em uma parte do banco do banco de dados e ninguém mais pode mexer nele até você terminar e destravar.

Isso tem a desvantagem de impedir o prosseguimento de outros acessos em algumas circunstâncias e exige uma atitude correta por parte da aplicação para lidar com isso e para lidar com os [*deadlocks*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64484/101) possíveis causados pelos travamentos. Dependendo da tecnologia adotada o travamento pode ser o banco de dados todo.

Ele considera que algo dará errado e toma a decisão mais garantida para impedir colisão de acesso.

[image: Diagrama mostrando com as transações operam do jeito pessimista]

O travamento otimista costuma escalar melhor porque ele não é um travamento de verdade, ele permite que outros acessem ao mesmo tempo. Ele é mais complexo de implementar em um sistema gerenciador de banco de dados e pode ser menos eficiente já que precisa garantir que não houve alterações no meio do processo quando começou o processo de manipulação e quando terminou de fazer, tendo que tomar alguma providência se houve alterações, muitas vezes abortando a transação e tendo que começar de novo, o que não é um problema se raramente acontece um conflito, e o padrão da maioria das aplicações é ser raro mesmo. A aplicação precisa saber manipular uma falha de transação.

[image: Diagrama mostrando com as transações operam do jeito otimista]

Note que mesmo o travamento pessimista pode ocorrer automaticamente pelo SGBD e você não precisaria se preocupar. Em alguns casos é feito o otimista automaticamente e o pessimista fica a critério do usuário que fará o acesso.

Cada produto entrega a forma que acha mais conveniente, pode ter ambos, um deles ou nenhum. Uma forma muto simples e eficiente é não permitir escritas concorrentes, só permite a serialização completa. Boa parte dos problemas não precisam disso e alguns bancos de dados mais nichados adotam esta forma, pode ser mais efetivo do que parece, mas obviamente não atende 100% das necessidades, quem sabe 99 ou 99,9%.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que significa serialização completa nesse contexto de bancos?

Comment: Só pode fazer uma transação de cada vez. Ele faz a transação completa, termina e vai para a próxima. Não tem concorrência verdadeira. Isso evita um monte de problemas e altamente eficiente. Em muitos cenários é uma maravilha, o problema dela é que se tiver uma transação demorada, todas as outras terão que esperar, mas esse não é um cenário comum na maioria dos problemas e na média ele é muito mais rápido, ele só tem alguma dificuldade nos raros picos que podem ser administrados ou em problemas que tenham muitas transações longas. Note que isso é só para escrita, a leitura está sempre livre.